# como guardar en el escritorio?

Tags: java, eclipse

mi pregunta es como hacer un String de ruta de archivo que siempre apunte al escritorio sin importar si se cambia la aplicacion de una pc a otra.
Me refiero a que si la aplicacion la cambian de pc siempre guarde un archivo en el escritorio.

Gracias

Comment: Has probado algo? Lo que has probado, que te muestra? Tienes algún error?

Comment: si he probado varias combinaciones como %USERS/DESKTOP% y este es el error que me da: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Desktop\FirstPdf.pdf (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada

Comment: Creo que debes usar `C:\%UserProfile%\Desktop\`, recuerdo que alguna vez lo usé para algo parecido.

Answer (score 5):

Tiene varias formas, en mis primeros códigos cuando necesité hacer algo similar, lo hacia con

```
String desktopPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop";
System.out.println(desktopPath.replace("\\", "/"));
```

es sencillo, y devuelve el String de la ruta del home del usuario, independiente si es Linux o Windows.
Lo malo es si la carpeta Desktop no existe dentro del home del usuario.

Otra forma es hacerlo con [FileSystemView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html) (si no te molesta combinar Java Core con Java Swing)

```
File home = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory();
```

y así obtienes un File con la información

y si lo necesitas como String `String absPath = home.getAbsolutePath();`

buscando por StackOverflow en inglés encontré una respuesta [solo para windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1080900)
quizás te interese

Comment: hola gracias por responder, muy amable, funciona tu propuesta solo que no me deja guardar el archivo porque dice acceso denegado, debe ser que falta algun permiso. sabes algo sobre eso?

Comment: posiblemente sea problema de permisos de la misma carpeta donde lo estás creando, prueba crear primero una subcarpeta con todos los permisos de escritura

Comment: Hola, MALA MIA, era que no estaba dandole nombre al archivo, gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score -3):

Como el ejemplo debes poner la ruta mi usuario es "gavo" y debes reemplazarlo al tuyo.

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile( jasperPrint, "C:/Users/gavo/Documents/reporte.pdf");
```

Comment: Eso no sirve. El OP quiere que funcione aunque cambies de usuario de sistema o de maquina.